# How to print max index of 5 values without using containers efficiently in c++?

Tags: c++

The indexes of the 5 values starts with `1`, my task is to print the index that has maximum value. I've tried the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int  a, b, c, d, e;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
    int cnt = 1;
    if (a < b){
        a = b;
        cnt++;
    }
    if (a < c){
        a = c;
        cnt++;
    }
    if (a < d){
        a = d;
        cnt++;
    }
    if (a < e){
        a = e;
        cnt++;
    }
    cout << cnt;

}
```

Is there any way to shortcut my code into less lines for example, or a way that is more efficient, Assuming all values are >= 0

Comment: That code doesn't do what you described, you should replace `cnt++` with `cnt = 2`, `cnt = 3`, etc.

Comment: Another problem with last if, assigning d, instead of e

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Aren't they the same?, can you explain please?

Comment: The last assignment doesn't matter, since you never use `a` after that.

Comment: @AliceWhite No, they're not the same. If the first test fails, you don't increment `cnt`, so the second one will set it to `2` instead of `3`.

Comment: @AliceWhite if the list was `(1, 0, 5, 4, 3)` then `cnt` would be incremented in the `a < c` if statement and nowhere else, so it would output 2.

Comment: I don't think you can get any more efficient than this. You have to check each element at least once, and you only check them once. And there isn't really any way to simplify without using some kind collection like array or vector.

Comment: @AliceWhite If the use of vectors etc are not allowed can you edit the title and change "array" to "collection" so tired dummies like myself don't misunderstand?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proposed solution that does not use containers, just STL algorithms and iterator magic.  It also works for any number of numbers entered, not just 5.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
    int maxv = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int high_index;
    int curIndex = 1;
    std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}, 
                  std::istream_iterator<int>{}, [&](int n) 
                  { 
                    if (maxv < n)
                    {
                        high_index = curIndex;
                        maxv = n;
                    }
                    ++curIndex; 
                });
    std::cout << "Highest index: " << high_index;
}
```

[Live Example](https://www.ideone.com/g4rKUH)

Comment: Upvoting as it's my solution written by someone who actually knows C++ :-)

Comment: updooting that comment because i remember that

Answer (score 3):

My C++ is not good, so treat this answer as pseudocode:

```
int max;
int maxIndex = 1;
cin >> max;
for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  if (n > max) {
    max = n;
    maxIndex = i;
  }
}
cout << maxIndex;
```

Comment: if they enter all negative numbers less than `-1` this would give the wrong answer

Comment: now they're inputting 6 numbers instead of 5, also `maxIndex` is off by 1

Comment: No, I changed to a < in the loop, and then ninja edited the maxIndex to i+1 when you weren't looking :-)

Comment: although the clean solution would have been to start with i = 2 -- I'll do that

Comment: i would probably write a for loop with `i` going from 1 to 5 (or from 0 to 4 even) and make the if statement say `if (i == 0 || n > max)` but i won't complain about your boundary condition - those are always a wee bit messy to have to write

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea -- avoids repeating code outside the loop and inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `std::max`.

```
if ((a = std::max(a, b)) == b) {
    cnt = 2;
}
if ((a = std::max(a, c)) == c) {
    cnt = 3;
}
if ((a = std::max(a, d)) == d) {
    cnt = 4;
}
if ((a = std::max(a, e)) == e) {
    cnt = 5;
}
```

I don't think it'll get much better than a series of if statements, without actually utilizing an array.

Note the above code will output the index of the *last* instance of the largest number: if the list were `(5, 5, 5, 5, 1)` it would output `4`.  If you want the *first* instance of the largest number, then your original code (with `cnt++` suitably replaced) is probably already the clearest solution.  Also, IMHO your solution is arguably clearer than what I just wrote.